# How to Refresh the Recyclerive List Items UI Paging 3

Tags: android-paging-3

The problem is that whenever I call adapter.refresh(), new items are added but the previous item's UI is not refreshed.basically a button showing in list item ,by click on that button doing something in another activity when i return back it should hide .